# Installing Virtual box on a fresh SLES 11 machine - python

Tags: installation, virtualbox, rpm, suse

How can I install virtual box on a fresh SLES 11 machine?

I've downloaded the rpm from:

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.6/VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586.rpm
```

And when i tried `yast2 -i` or `rpm -ivh`, I get these error:

```
 Package VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586.rpm could not be installed.

 Details:
 Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed: error: Failed dependencies:
         libasound.so.2 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586
         libGL.so.1 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586    
         libICE.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586   
         libSDL-1.2.so.0 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i58
         libSM.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586    
         libX11.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586   
         libXcursor.so.1 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i58
         libXext.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586  
         libXinerama.so.1 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i5
         libXmu.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586   
         libXrender.so.1 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i58
         libXt.so.6 is needed by VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586
```

I've tried:

```
# zypper install libasound libGL libSDL
```

but it doesn't install...

```
Retrieving repository 'SLES-11-SDK-SP3-Updates' metadata [done]
Building repository 'SLES-11-SDK-SP3-Updates' cache [done]
Retrieving repository 'SLES-11-SP3-Updates' metadata [done]
Building repository 'SLES-11-SP3-Updates' cache [done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libGL' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libGL' found.
'libSDL' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libSDL' found.
'libasound' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'libasound' found.
Resolving package dependencies...
```

Currently, these are the repos added:

```
# zypper repos
# | Alias                   | Name                                           | Enabled | Refresh
--+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------+---------+--------
1 | SLES-11-RZG-SP3         | SLES-11-RZG-SP3                                | Yes     | Yes    
2 | SLES-11-SDK-SP3-Updates | SLES-11-SDK-SP3-Updates                        | Yes     | Yes    
3 | SLES-11-SP3             | SLES-11-SP3                                    | Yes     | Yes    
4 | SLES-11-SP3-Updates     | SLES-11-SP3-Updates                            | Yes     | Yes    
5 | devel_tools_scm         | Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP2) | Yes     | No
```

from `uname -a`:

```
Linux ws4-clarind 3.0.101-0.8-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 1 12:51:09 UTC 2013 (2417eb9) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

I did have some issues with installing VirtualBox. Finally I got a solution and wrote a blog post about it. Hope that helps:

```
uname -a
Linux dq1bc01b08 3.0.76-0.11-default #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990) x86_64 x86_64         x86_64 GNU/Linux

zypper in kernel-default-devel-3.0.76-0.11.1.x86_64
zypper in autoconf bison flex gcc gcc-c++ make m4

cp -f /boot/config-$(uname -r) /usr/src/linux/.config
cd /usr/src/linux
make prepare
make modules_prepare

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.8/VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.8_92456_sles11.0-1.x86_64.rpm
zypper install VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.8_92456_sles11.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

in more detail: http://ehaselwanter.com/en/blog/2014/03/22/install-virtualbox-on-sles-11-sp3/

Comment: Please include a summary of the answer in case the provided link goes away.  Link-only answers are not as useful on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing those dependencies and trying again.

A quick Google search makes me thing that SLES doesn't use yum/apt-get, but "Zypper" for a package manager via command line.

[Zypper Documentation](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage)

```
zypper install libasound libGL libSDL etc
```

Comment: doesn't even have dependencies for the dependencies. it's a vicious cycle of infinite zypper...

Answer (score 0):

`uname -a` report:

```
Linux ws4-clarind [...] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And you are trying to install:

```
VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.i586.rpm
```

The problem is that you are trying to install a **32 bits** version of Virtualbox on a **64 bit** system. You should use this one: VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.x86_64.rpm at
 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.6/VirtualBox-4.3-4.3.6_91406_sles11.0-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Still stuck on this one ?

Comment: yep. it's impossible because of the 101 dependencies, i gave up and let a SUSE expert install the dependencies for me.