# How do I install apt4suse on SLES 11?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, apt, suse

**How should apt4suse be installed in SLES 11?**

The version on my machine is:

```
# uname -a
Linux ws4-clarind 3.0.101-0.8-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 1 12:51:09 UTC 2013 (2417eb9) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
Release:    11
Codename:   n/a

# cat /etc/*-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
```

I've tried installing with the following commands:

```
# wget http://linux01.gwdg.de/~scorot/install-apt4suse.rpm
# rpm -Uvh install-apt4suse.rpm
# install-apt4suse
```

But it didn't install successfully:

```
# wget http://linux01.gwdg.de/~scorot/install-apt4suse.rpm
--2014-01-23 07:51:36--  http://linux01.gwdg.de/~scorot/install-apt4suse.rpm
Resolving linux01.gwdg.de... 134.76.13.21
Connecting to linux01.gwdg.de|134.76.13.21|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16553 (16K) [application/x-rpm]
Saving to: `install-apt4suse.rpm.1'

100%[======================================>] 16,553      --.-K/s   in 0.01s   

2014-01-23 07:51:36 (1.09 MB/s) - `install-apt4suse.rpm.1' saved [16553/16553]

# rpm -Uvh install-apt4suse.rpm
warning: install-apt4suse.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5e00df4c
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package install-apt4suse-0.2.6-1.noarch is already installed
# install-apt4suse
Setup apt for SuSE Linux 11 on x86_64...

Downloading apt and apt-libs packages...
No such directory `pub/linux/suse/apt/SuSE/11-x86_64/RPMS.suser-jmorris'.

unlink: No such file or directory
No such directory `pub/linux/suse/apt/SuSE/11-x86_64/RPMS.suser-jmorris'.

unlink: No such file or directory

Done.
error: File not found by glob: /tmp/apt-*
package apt-libs is not installed
Package apt-libs is not installed
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't use zypper(1) which comes with SLES? You might want to consider putting this to Unix & Linux or ServerFault which seem more appropriate to this kind of a question (and would most likely draw more attention and answers there).

Comment: yes because zypper lacks many RPMs in the repo!! even simply upgrading python to the latest version is a PITA...

Comment: SLES is by nature such a beast. If you want bleeding edge things, you really should consider using another distribution as SLES is specifically geared towards maximum compatibility and conservativity as well. Adding OpenSUSE repositories to zypper will give you some benefits, but will also void your Suse Support Contract.

Comment: Try `rpm -Uvh install-apt4suse.rpm.1`

Comment: @SamiLaine, my employers gave me a supercomputer and a crappy OS... Also i've tired adding OpenSUSE repos, it doesn't help...

Comment: Please notice that you have already installed package instal-apt4suse rpm. You don't need to install it again.

Comment: The RPM is installed but the apt4suse isn't...

Comment: BTW Apt-rpm seems abandoned years ago. My rpm-based distribution uses apt too but it's a fork which is supported by team members and lacks a lot of "advanced" features like deltarpm support etc. Afterall, if you really hate SuSE "native" package management utils and have enough diskspace you may create a virtual Linux environment of your choice right in your homedir. The simplest way to organize a "flyweight" virtualization is to use chroot().

Comment: i can't even install virtualbox on the suse, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286196/installing-virtual-box-on-a-fresh-sles-11-machine-python/21493905?noredirect=1#21493905